# JAXBException in XML but not JSON

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

SOLVED - I had to add @XmlSeeAlso to my Aardvark class for the XML to show RESTfully (shown below)

I am trying to RESTfully display the following in both XML and JSON.  When I run the test case shown below (outside of REST) it works fine. When I view it RESTfully in the browser as JSON it works fine.  When I view it RESTfully in the browser as XML I get the following error:

```
"JAXBException occurred : class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.."
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:594‌​) 
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:648) 
... 74 more
```

I am using jackson 2.2.2.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Banana.class)
        Banana b = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal("myXmlFile");  
        context.createMarshaller().marshal(b,System.err);

        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BananaHolder.class)
        BananaHolder bh = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal("myOtherXmlFile");  
        context.createMarshaller().marshal(bh,System.err);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class Banana {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapOfAardvarkListsAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, List<Aardvark>> map;
}

public class MapOfAardvarkListsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AardvarkListWrapper, Map<String, List<Aardvark>>> {
    public Map<String, List<Aardvark>> unmarshal(AardvarkListWrapper wrapper) {...}
    public AardvarkListWrapper  marshal(Map<String, List<Aardvark>> map) {...}
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class AardvarkListWrapper  {
    @XmlElement
    private List<MapOfAardvarksEntry> list;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class MapOfAardvarksEntry {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String key;
    @XmlElement
    private List<Aardvark> value;
}   

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso(ArrayList.class) // Needed to resolve hotdogs in XML
public class Aardvark {
    private Map<String,Object> hotdogs;
    ...
}

/// REST SIDE
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class BananaHolder {
    public List<Banana> bananas;
}

public class TheRestClass {
    @GET
    @PATH("/")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response getAllBananas(){
        List<Banana> bananas = ...
        BananaHolder holder = new BananaHolder();
        holder.setBananas(bananas);
        return Response.ok(holder).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: The web logs have a stacktrace but it's nothing that points at my code.

Comment: What about in the server logs?  Also that exception shouldn't be an `IllegalAnnotationException`, are you seeing it as one?

Comment: at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:594)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:648)
...

Comment: Blaise, I got past the IllegalAnnotationException earlier on and forgot to edit the header before posting. Sorry about that. I fixed the header

Comment: When you say "view it in the browser" are you calling a RESTful service?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling a RESTful service

Comment: Does the RESTful service return a List of your domain object?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. When I call the REST service I get a page with the JAXBException message.  I expect to get the XML representation of the Banana class

Comment: Did you write the RESTful service?

Comment: I did not write it, but I think I know what you're referring to.  The REST call returns a BananaListHolder object in the response, which is a wrapper for a List<Banana> object